# Iterative Fibonacci algorithm giving me a wrong result after fib(47)

Tags: c, fibonacci

I am using the iterative fib algorithm that I have copied below. I have found this algorithm on Rosetta code and it gives me the correct answer up until fib(46). After that it the values are wrong. Does anyone know why this is the case?

```
long long fibb(int n)
{
    int fnow = 0, fnext = 1, tempf;
    while(--n > 0) {
        tempf = fnow + fnext;
        fnow = fnext;
        fnext = tempf;
    }
    return fnext;   
}
```

Output:

```
Fib(46) = 1836311903            <---- Correct
Fib(47) = 18446744092385799393   <---- Wrong (Correct Answer is: 2971215073)
```

Comment: Consider using type `uintmax_t` for all variables (except `n`) for maximum integer range.

Comment: Answers below about overflow are correct, but since your sample code doesn't show the code to generate the actual output, it doesn't explain how the printed value is also larger than signed int 32...  Overflow integers wrap around, they can never get larger that INT_MAX since they are still contained in 32 bits.

Comment: @Brad Looks you nailed the true issue.  Hmmm: Brad vs Brandon - not some evil twin persona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you are using temporary variables of type `int` in your code rather than type `long long int`. This means that if you get to the point where you're dealing with sufficiently large Fibonacci numbers, you'll get an integer overflow in your code. In particular, the 47th Fibonacci number is 2,971,215,073, which is too large to fit in a signed 32-bit integer, so you'll get an overflow.

Changing your temporary variables to type `long long int` (or, better yet, `uint64_t`) should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `long long` also for `fnow, fnext, and tempf`, try:

```
long long int fnow = 0, fnext = 1, tempf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your variables long long instead of int. 'int' depending on the machine could be 64, 32, 16 or 8-bits.

If you want to specify the size of the integer yourself and make a portable code then make use of uint8_t, uint16_t, etc or int8_t, int16_t, etc. The 'u' stands for unsigned. This is a part of the stdint.h library!